# Issue in supporting multiple screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this question have been asked several times, but, I am facing a unique problem, solution of which I have not been able to find.

I have images in drawable, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi in ratio of .75:1:1.5:2:3 respectively.

For most of the emulators, images are appearing perfectly well, but, for some of them, images are not appearing in proper proportion.

Like images appears well in 3.2" HVGA slider(ADPI) emulator- 320x480 mdpi, but, images do not appear well in 5.1" WVGA emulator- 480x800 mdpi. This is despite the fact that both are mdpi.

Why is it that despite both of them being mdpi, images appears well in one and do not appear in proper proportion in the other? How can I overcome this.

Edit: 
[Image where it shows mdpi:
3.2" HVGA slider(ADPI) emulator- 320x480 mdpi and 5.1" WVGA emulator- 480x800 mdpi.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SAX0.png)

EDIT2: 
[image: This is what settings of my emulator looks like:]

Comment: @Der Golem: Please have a look at the EDIT.

Answer (score -1):

I think I had a similar issue where the dp wasn't being scaled well for monitor resolution. In the device settings under 'startup size and orientation', switch the scale to something like `4dp on device = 1px on screen`.

In Android Virtual Device Manager:

[image: Startup size and orientation]

Comment: Could you please elaborate further. I cannot find these options in the emulator. Also, it would be extremely nice if you could please share which link/tutorial did you follow in supporting multiple screens.

Comment: I don't think your issue is the layouts - as you said, you have images in the appropriate folders. Added a photo to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you please refer the EDIT2 in my question, because, that is how the settings of my emulator looks like.

Comment: Sorry, not sure about eclipse. The standard is Android Studio now.